# C - How to pass part of a string without copying to a new string?

Tags: c

In C, say I have:

```
char *hash = argv[1];
```

How could I pass the first two characters of hash to a function expecting a string as a parameter? Preferably without creating a new string consisting of those first 2 characters.

Comment: You cannot if it has to be null-terminated.

Comment: If this is a duplicate of a commonly asked question, could I get some insight on the type of terms that I could have used when searching?

Comment: You can pass the pointer all together, then in the target function you can get the first two chars of it. You can't do this without modifying the original with a null character.

Comment: @zerkms, "it" being the expected parameter of the function?

Comment: You can modify `argv[1]`. Insert a `'\0'` after the part you wish to pass. If you are going to use the full string later, you can save whatever was in the place before you inserted the null. Obviously this only needs `O(1)` extra storage (exactly `1` `char `in fact) rather than `O(n)` for copying the string.

Comment: @EOF in both cases it's `O(1)`: the length of the string to be copied/passed is fixed and known and not linear to the original string length.

Comment: @zerkms I can pass as long a string as I please to the program.

Comment: @EOF that's right, and you only need to copy 2 characters from it, regardless of the length of the string you pass. Hence it's constant not linear.

Comment: @zerkms Ah, true. Though the method I propose allows for arbitrarily long prefixes to be passed (though the extra storage increases by including a position).

Comment: If it is indeed only _two_ characters, you can pass `hash[0]` and `hash[1]` as characters.

Comment: Say the string does not need to be 0 terminated. What is the C syntax for hash[0:2]?

Comment: There is no such syntax in C. A string by definition is NULL-terminated. Just pass the pointer and let the function use the first two characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the chars in question as individual chars and not strings, then just pass in the string to the function as it wants and explicitly reference the two chars that you want.

```
void printTwoChars(char *str) {
    char *charA, *charB;

    charA = &str[0];
    charB = &str[1];

    printf("--%c--%c--\n", *charA, *charB);
}

int main(void) {
    char hash[] = "hello world";

    printTwoChars(hash);
}
```

output:

```
--h--e--
```

Comment: I guess avoiding copying the *nul-character* qualifies as not making a complete copy. (though a copy is probably cheaper than the function call overhead.... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities come to mind, both of them involve bad coding:

- change the function to accept a string with optional length, so it will use only the first n chars, then send the original string with length 2
- change the 3rd char to null, send to the function. If you need the string it's harder - you'll need to copy the 3rd char to a temp location, and when it returns change it back. This is all assuming the string isn't constant and the function is synchronous